# AWS SQS with mysql and C# with hundreds of thousands messages

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading, amazon-sqs

I am working with aws sqs queue. The queue may having massive messages i.e if i do not process there will be more than a million mesasge per hour.

I am processing all the messages and putting them into a mysql table. Innodb with 22 columns. Insert on Duplicate Key Update. I have a primary key and unique key.

I am working with C# where i ran 80 threads in order to pull messages from sqs.

I applied transaction in c# run the query like "insert on duplicate key update"
at the same time i am using lock in c# so only single thread can update the table. if id do not use C# lock then an exception is thrown from mysql dead lock occured.

Problem is here i can see there are a lot of threads are waiting before C# lock and this time gradually increasing. Can any body suggest me what is the best way to do this..

Note, i have  8GB RAM intell xeon 2.53 with 1GE internet speed. please suggest me in this regard.

Comment: Bulk inserts often require you to use different techniques from normal inserts. Have you read [the](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-speed.html) [relevant](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html)?

Comment: but i do not have file..i have a in memory  list<Object> . do you want me to write data first on disk then load from there ?

Answer (score 1):

If I were to do it, the C# program would primarily be creating the CSV file to empty your SQS queue. Or at least a significant chunk of it. The file would then be used for bulk insert into an empty non-indexed in anyway worktable. I would steer for non-temporary but whatever. I see no reason to add `temporary` to the mix when this is recurring, and when done the worktable is truncated anyway.

The bulk insert would be achieved through `LOAD DATA FROM INFILE` fired off from the c# program. Alternatively, a value in a new row in some other table could be written with an incrementer saying file2 is ready, file3 is ready, and the LOAD happens in an event triggered, say every n minutes. An event that was put together with mysql Create Event. Six of one, half dozen of another.

But the benefits of a sentinal, a mutex, might be of value, as this whole thing happens in batches. And the next batch(es) to be processed need to be suspended while this occurs. Let's call this concept `The Blocker`, and the one being worked on is row `N`.

Ok, now your data is in the worktable. And it is safe from being stomped on until processed. Let's say you have 250k rows. Other batches shortly to follow. If you have special processing to have happen, you may wish to create indexes. But at this moment there are none.

You perform a normal `insert on duplicate key update` (IODKU) to the REAL table using this worktable. It would, in that IODKU follow a normal `insert into select` pattern, where the `select` part comes from the worktable.

At the end of that statement, the worktable is truncated, any indexes dropped, row `N` has its status set to complete, and `The Blocker` is free to work on row `N+1` when it appears.

The indexes are dropped to facilitate the next round of bulk insert, where maintaining indexes is of least importance. And indexes on the worktable may very well be overhead baggage unnecessary during IODKU.

In this manner, you get the best of both worlds

- [LOAD DATA FROM INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)
- [IODKU](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

And the focus is taken off of multi-threading, a good thing to take one's focus off of.

Here is a nice article on performance and strategies titled [Testing the Fastest Way to Import a Table into MySQL](http://dbahire.com/testing-the-fastest-way-to-import-a-table-into-mysql-and-some-interesting-5-7-performance-results/). Don't let the mysql version of the title or inside the article scare you away. Jumping to the bottom and picking up some conclusions:

> The fastest way you can import a table into MySQL without using raw
>   files is the LOAD DATA syntax. Use parallelization for InnoDB for
>   better results, and remember to tune basic parameters like your
>   transaction log size and buffer pool. Careful programming and
>   importing can make a >2-hour problem became a 2-minute process. You
>   can disable temporarily some security features for extra performance

---

I would separate the C# routine entirely from the actual LOAD DATA and IODKU update effort and leave that to the event mentioned with Create Event for several reasons. Mainly better design. As such the C# program is only dealing with SQS and writing out files with incrementing file #'s.